# multiple attribute form output

Tags: php, html, forms

i have had made a number of changes to the below program but am really stumped on my last task-  i need a multiple attribute to pull multiple 'teams' data (points,goal difference etc) with php form. i can get single teams to work but not multiple. see screen attached and heres my code below.
![enter image description here][1]

```
   <html>
<head>
    <style>
        .red {color: red}
    </style>
    <title>Table</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php



 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"  ){

    $tablesPage = "http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/tables";

    if(!empty($_POST["team"])){

        $teamData= getTeamData($_POST["team"] , $tablesPage); //get associative array of team data

        if(!empty($_POST["data"]) && $_POST["data"] == "results"){

            echo getResults($teamData);
        } else if(!empty($_POST["data"]) && $_POST["data"] == "position"){

            echo getPosition($teamData); 

        } else if(!empty($_POST["data"]) && $_POST["data"] == "two points for a win"){

            echo getPoints($teamData); 

        } else if(!empty($_POST["data"]) && $_POST["data"] == "goal difference"){

            echo getDifference($teamData); 

        }
    }
}


function getPosition($teamData){
    /*This function takes an array of team data and returns a string containing the name of the team and its position in the leauge */

    return  "Team ". $teamData["team"]  ." are currently number " . $teamData["position"] . "  in the league " ;
}

function getResults($teamData){
    /*This function takes an array of team data and returns a string containing the results of the team */

    return  $teamData["team"]  ." have won " . $teamData["won"] . " , drawn " . $teamData["drew"] . " , and lost " . $teamData["lost"] . "  games to date  " ;
}

function getPoints($teamData){
    /*This function takes an array of team data and returns a string containing the points and calculates the old two points system */
    $oldpoints = $teamData["won"] * 2 + $teamData["drew"];

    return  $teamData["team"]  ." have " . $teamData["points"] . " points under the current system " .  "<br> Under two points for a win they would have " . $oldpoints ;
}

function getDifference($teamData){
    /*This function takes an array of team data and returns a string containing the name of the team and its goal difference in the leauge */

    return  $teamData["team"]  ." goal difference is " . $teamData["difference"] . " at the moment " ;
}

function getTeamData($team, $tablesPage){
    /* This function takes a webpage url and the name of a team as two string arguments. e.g. getTeam(""http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/tables", "liverpool")
    It returns an array of data about the team. 

    You don't need to understand what this function does just that it returns an array which contains keya and values. The values map to the following keys:
    "position", "team", "played", "won", "drew", "lost", "for", "against", "difference", "points"


    */
    $html = new DOMDocument(); 
    @$html->loadHtmlFile($tablesPage); //use DOM
    @$xpath = new DOMXPath($html); //use XPath
    $items = $xpath->query('//td/a[text()="' . $team . '"]/../..'); //get the relevant table row
    $values[] =  array();
    foreach($items as $node){
        foreach($node->childNodes as $child) {
        if($child->nodeType == 1) array_push($values, $child->nodeValue); //KLUDGE
        }
    }
    $values[2]  = substr($values[2], -1); //KLUDGE
    $values = array_slice( $values, 2, count($values)-4); //KLUDGE
    $keys = array("position", "team", "played", "won", "drew", "lost", "for", "against", "difference", "points");
    return array_combine($keys, $values);
}


?>

<br>
Select a team and a data item about that team
<form  method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<select name="team[]" multiple="multiple" size="3"> 
<option value=""></option>
  <option value="Everton">Everton</option>
  <option value="Arsenal">Arsenal</option>
  <option value="Chelsea">Chelsea</option>
  <option value="Man Utd">Man Utd</option>
  <option value="Liverpool">Liverpool</option>
</select>
<select name="data">
  <option value="position">position</option>
  <option value="results">results</option>
  <option value="two points for a win">two points for a win</option>
  <option value="goal difference">goal difference</option>
<select>
<input type="submit" value="Get Data"></input>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just delete the lines that start /*debug */. Please remember to accept the answer if you like it :-)

Comment: Have removed the debug code from the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that you need to replace. I have left the 'debug' code in so you can see what is happening. just delete it when you are done.

Removed debug code.

Tested code: PHP 5.3.18 on windows xp.

```
<?php


 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"  ){

    $tablesPage = "http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/tables";

    if(!empty($_POST["team"])){

        // remember that the $_POST['team'] is an array of team names
        foreach($_POST['team'] as $currentTeam) {
            $teamData= getTeamData($currentTeam , $tablesPage); //get associative array of team data

            if(!empty($_POST["data"]) && $_POST["data"] == "results"){

                echo getResults($teamData);
            } else if(!empty($_POST["data"]) && $_POST["data"] == "position"){

                echo getPosition($teamData);

            } else if(!empty($_POST["data"]) && $_POST["data"] == "two points for a win"){

                echo getPoints($teamData);

            } else if(!empty($_POST["data"]) && $_POST["data"] == "goal difference"){

                echo getDifference($teamData);

            }
            echo '<br />';
        } // end currentTeam
    }
}
```

Comment: brilliant ! i had taken a different path and it was driving me mad!how do i prevent the output at the start ie.

 array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "Arsenal" [1]=> string(7) "Chelsea" [2]=> string(7) "Man Utd" } Arsenal have won 19 , drawn 7 , and lost 7 games to date
Chelsea have won 22 , drawn 6 , and lost 5 games to date
Man Utd have won 17 , drawn 6 , and lost 10 games to date